# Python Tkinter: can a slider widget control another slider widget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, slider

[image]

I have a controller slider with 10 positions at which it loads a different set of values to set its three sub-sliders. I use a callback to load and set each widget with the `widget.set(value)` command. I also keep a reference to the widget's variable that I also set independently with the value.

The problem is that I can verify that the values are correctly loaded and set, both on the widget itself and in the variable reference, but **the handle of the target widgets wont bulge**.

I know it's doable, I've done it before, I just can't find the code. I think it was just a matter of setting the widget to the value. But it's apparently not the case as I can't do it here. I have tried setting the widget only, its variable reference only, both, I have even tried the config option `widget.config(variable = value)`. All correctly set the widget. Is there a trick I'm missing to have the target widget's handle reflect the value and be set at the correct position?

Comment: provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It won't be possible, it's part of an app and has too many dependencies for just a code bit to work, BUT, in trying to produce a simpler working example, the .set() command actually worked and effectively set the subslider's handle. Which made me look deeper into my code and discover that one pointer to a reference was wrong but did not raise any exception nor affect the overall state of the app....

Answer (score 1):

If someone stumbles upon this question: I have built a minimal reproductible example of my problem, and it turns out that implemented like this, the function works perfectly well. Second slider does nothing, first slider sets the second one

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, parent)

        self.var1 = tk.IntVar(name = "var1")
        self.var2 = tk.DoubleVar(name="var2")
        self.panel = ttk.Frame()

        # The master slider callback
        def selectorAfter(event):
            v = [1.02, 30.4, 51.0, 65.5, 81.17, 11.11, 50.00, 0.0]
            # Either setting slider or variable will work
            self.var2.set(v[int(event)])
            ## self.slider2.set(v[int(event)])
            print(event)

        # The sub slider callback    
        def sliderAfter(event):
            print(event)

        self.slider1 = tk.Scale(self.panel, name = "slider1", variable= self.var1, from_= 0, to= 7, length=330, width=10, orient='horizontal', command = selectorAfter)
        self.slider2 = tk.Scale(self.panel, name = "slider2", variable= self.var2, from_= 0.0, to= 100.0, length=330, width=10, orient='horizontal', command = sliderAfter)

    # def body(self):
        self.panel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.slider1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.slider2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Gui(None)
    app.title('Example')
    app.mainloop()
```